# Shorter way to write list-as-dict-value in Python?

Tags: python

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
a = {
     'red': ['yellow', 'green', 'purple'],
     'orange': ['fuschia']
    }
```

This is the code I write to add new elements:

```
if a.has_key(color):
    a[color].append(path)
else:
    a[color] = [path]
```

Is there a shorter way to write this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(list)
```

Now you just need:

```
mydict[color].append(path)
```

`defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict` that can be initialized to a list, integer...

---

btw, the use of `has_key` is discouraged, and in fact `has_key` has been removed from  python 3.2.
When needed, use this by far more pythonic idiom instead:

```
if color in a:
    ........
```

Comment: even better is
try:
  a[color].append(path)
except KeyError:
  a[color] = [path]

... and this comment formatting is broken :)

Comment: @blaze try/except is better? I'd say not.

Comment: if try is usually successful and exception isn't raised - it's effective. one less "if" to check.

Comment: lots of stuff happening around checking whether operation goes right and whether exception is thrown. besides the semantics of "exception" should be that something, well, exceptional is taking place. I'd avoid using exceptions for regular code flow if a convenient alternative exists